# database.query prepare statement binding not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have this prepare statement working

```
String [] selectionArgs = new String[]{level, col1, col1_value};

db.query(Table, null,                      //table & columns
         level + " = ? AND " +             //selection 
            "? != ? AND " +
            "length(" + col1 + ") = " + col1.length,  //**here is question point**
         selectionArgs,                    // selectionArgs
         null, null, "RANDOM()",           // order by
         Integer.toString(count));         // number of retrieve
```

Notice that length is raw Inline. not with "?" and it's working.

But when I change it to as the following

```
String [] selectionArgs = new String[]{level, col1, col1_value, 
                                   col1, Integer.toString(col1.length)}; //added for length

db.query(Table, null,                      //table & columns
         level + " = ? AND " +             //selection 
            "? != ? AND " +
            "length(?) = ?",  //**here is question point**
         selectionArgs,                    // selectionArgs
         null, null, "RANDOM()",           // order by
         Integer.toString(count));         // number of retrieve
```

It is not working anymore.

Does anyone have any idea why it is. If u have, please give me some explanation. Give my thanks to u all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` to bind literal values only, not identifiers such as column names.

So the `? != ?` with `"col1", "col1_value"` args is the same as `'col1' != 'col1_value'` and the expression is always true.

Also `length(?) = ?` with `"col1", "4"` is the same as `length('col1') = 4` which is also always true. But in your first form you have it like `length(col1) = 4` which tests the length of the value in column `col1` and not the literal `'col1'` so there's a chance it is true only for those rows you're interested in, and that's why it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

As I have noticed your query,you are converting your Integer value to string by using **Integer.toString(col1)** and than later you are trying to compare this string value with Integer value lenght(?).

your previous query is working because you are not converting your value in String. both length(col1) will return integer and col1.length also return integer.

working query -->"length(" + col1 + ") = " + **col1.length**,  //here is question point

but in this case length(?) is returning integer and the next "?" which is Integer.toString(col1) is string value so here is type mismatch in case of comparision.
Not working query --> "length(?) = **?** ",  //here is question point